# textarea, remove display:none added from js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to remove `display:none` added to a textform from javascript

Checking chrome console i see this "horrible" thing:

```
<textarea class="form-control " cols="10" rows="10" fieldset="input_default" id="message" name="message" data-placeholder="my_test_placeholder" style="display: none;">
</textarea>
```

Uncorrect because you know with `display: none` textarea element is hidden

Unfortunately cannot remove the scripts in use right now so the only solution for me right now is to try to remove it from js or css. :(

Any idea ?

Comment: try `$('#message').css("display","none")`  or `$("#message").show()`

Comment: Thanks guys

Ive solved using a new class .form-fix with the solution proposed from Nick De Jaeger. 
Thanks everyone else for your suggestions, going to take care of em because i still have to finish the template.

Answer (score 1):

It should be as simple as a jquery select and method:

```
$('#message').show();
```

Answer (score 1):

using js

```
document.getelementbyid('message').style.display="block";
```

Comment: Be careful with capitalization for this full JS approach: `getElementById()`, not `getelementbyid()`

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this:

```
$('#message').css("display","block");

$('#message').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.form-control {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="form-control" cols="10" rows="10"
  fieldset="input_default" id="message" name="message"
  data-placeholder="my_test_placeholder" style="display: none;">
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way :

```
$('#message').show();
```

But to change all the css rules you want, use :

```
$('#message').css("display", "block");
```

---

And in CSS :

```
#message {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery give you [**show()**](http://api.jquery.com/show/) function for the task. It will show the element when you put the element `id` or `class` in the selector.

```
$('#message').show();
```

Also you can do same task using  [**css()**](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function

```
$('#message').css("display","block");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
    $("#message").show();
});
```

fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/yunw352p/